# map function in React-Native

Tags: typescript, react-native

I am new to React Native and I am using Typescript for my project. I am difficulty to do mapping in React Native. Below is my code for interface:

```
interface Teacher {
  name: string;
  sex: string;
  age: number;
  student: Student[];
}

interface Student {
  name: string;
  sex: string;
  address: string;
}
```

I don't have any problem mapping Teacher's interface but I am having difficulty on how to map Student interface when I use the map function in my code.

```
{Class.map(class => (
   <View>
      {class.student.map(class => (
          <Text>{class.name}</Text>
      ))}
      {class.student.map(class => (
          <Text>{class.sex}</Text>
      ))}
      {class.student.map(class => (
          <Text>{class.address}</Text>
      ))}
   </View>
)}
```

When I did my coding like this, I get an error `Cannot read property 'map' of undefined` in my console. Thank you in advance.

Comment: The code looks incomplete. I see a reference to `class.student` but I don't see an interface for `class`. In any case, you are overwriting the `class` var in your nested maps. `class.student.map(class` will overwrite value of `class` from the initial map, so the second use of `class` will not have a `student` property.

Answer (score 0):

you can try like this with create nested array.

```
interface Teacher {
  name: string;
  sex: string;
  age: number;
  student: Student[{
name: string;
  sex: string;
  address: string;
}];
}

{Teacher.map(({name,sex,address,student}) => (
   <View>
      {student.map(student => (
          <Text>{student.name}</Text>
          <Text>{student.sex}</Text>
          <Text>{student.address}</Text>
      ))}
   </View>
)}
```